# Export Swift framework for the usage in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, swift4

I am creating a framework using Swift to be used in my college's Objective-C Project. I have created a new project and have chosen **Cocoa Touch Framework** and named it **printFramework**. I have added a Swift file into the project with the code below:

```
import Foundation


@objc public class printClass : NSObject {
    @objc public override init() {
        print("My name is init")
    }

    @objc public func printMe(){
        print("Hello Wrold")
    }
}
```

I build the above code (Build Success) with the target **Generic iOS Device**, and now I have a briefcase (framework) file and under Product, 
and I create another **Single View Application** project with language Objective-C named **prinFrameTest**. I copied the framework into the project and in **General** tab under **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**, I have my **printFramwork** and above that in **Embedded Binaries** I have added my **printFramework**.

In my `ViewController.m` I have the following code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import printFramework;
#import <printFramework/printFramework-Swift.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    printClass *pr;
    [pr printMe];
}

@end
```

I build and run this (it ran successfully), Simulator opens and but the code is not working (means it does not print anything in the log).

What is going wrong?

Comment: start class names with Capital letters

Comment: @Sh_Khan tried and it does not worked BTW thanks for comment

Comment: see below answer this comment is irrelevant ,  you may build the frameWork again after you change the class name , but for now test it as it is

Comment: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) for the code below

Comment: @Sh_Khan edit my question you mean?

Comment: try edited answer below

Comment: tried and same error :-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) . @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use `[[YourClass alloc] init]` to make it work
2. in Xcode project, you need to enable `Always embed Swift standard libraries`
3. Building with `Generic iOS Device` does not produce a universal framework

Comment: for number 2 I have already done that before and for number 3 what should put instead of Generic iOS Device

Comment: @UncleJunior if you include the project directly, you don't need to care, but if you build to *.framework, you need to build for all architectures by using run script (try this https://medium.com/allatoneplace/writing-custom-universal-framework-in-xcode-9-and-ios-11-7a63a2ce024a)

Answer (score 1):

If you put a breakpoint on the line `[pr printMe]` and inspect the value of `pr`, you'll probably see that it's a null reference - you haven't created the object, you've just allocated a variable which can hold a reference to an instance of `printClass`. Try this way:

```
[[printClass new] printMe];
```

Comment: getting same error from Sh_Khan answer :  :-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @UncleJunior: I think that is mistake to import framework in your project. I have checked with my demo and this is working fine. You can check like: In your obj-c language project add swift file and add your swift code in this file and then add your swift file in obj-c controller #import "Your project name-Swift.h" then check

Comment: @UncleJunior: Your framework not linked perfectly with your obj-c language project thats why you are geting this error

Comment: This is exactly the question, I need to make it as framework, and I want to know where is the problem in linking it into Obj-C

Comment: Have you added your framework in ambedded binaries in general tab?

Comment: Yes I did it at first, and stated in the Question

Comment: @UncleJunior: Remove your derived data and clean your project then build

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a non nil object either

```
printClass *pr = [printClass new];
```

**OR**

```
printClass *pr = [[printClass alloc] init];
```